# django hide the sidebar/nav conditionally in the templates

Tags: python, html, django

I'm thinking of the best way to conditionally hide divs using Django. My guess is there is an elegant solution within the template language I'm not seeing. I can write a list and do a request.path not in maybe, but an indicator from the view or, even better, some better templating would be preferable. Any suggestions?

base.html

```
<body>
    {% include "header.html" %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        {% ifnotequal request.path '/accounts/login/' %}
            {% include 'leftpane.html' %}
        {% endifnotequal %} 
        <div id="main">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div> 
    {% include "footer.html" %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Add a block to include your leftpane.html on templates where you need it, ie:

in base.html:

```
<body>
    {% include "header.html" %}
    <div id="wrapper">{% block accounts %}{% endblock %}
        <div id="main">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div> 
    {% include "footer.html" %}
</body>
```

Then in other templates which need a leftpane (ie maybe not the homepage?), add the leftpane inside the empty base.html block, ie:

in accounts.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html %}

{% block accounts %}{% include 'leftpane.html' %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.